# Why my listview not found any record in yii2?

Tags: yii2

I have a dataprovider to search a world but my listview does not display any record? How can i send this query object to listview? 
every thing in my webpage is worked very good but at the output my list view show "not found any result" this mean my list view code is no have problem . problem is in my dataprovider and this query beacuse i customize that

my controller:

```
$query = new Query();
$dataProvidersearch=new ActiveDataProvider([
         'query'=>$query->from('tbl_post')->Where(['like', 'title', $search])-
>andWhere(['like', 'en_title', $search])->andWhere(['like', 'content', $search])->andWhere(['like', 'en_content', $search]),

    ]);
```

this is my list view in my view:

```
 $posts = $model->getModels();
           echo ListView::widget([
'dataProvider'=>$posts,
'itemView'=>'search',
'summary' => '',
'itemOptions' => [
     'tag' => false
 ],
```

]);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure you have enough code here for someone to help.  Even something simple like a listview could consist of a view, a controller, and two model files and your code could be failing at any of these points.  You may have simply forgot to include the listview library at the top of your view, but we can't see that in your current example.

What I would recommend is using Gii to generate a listview.  It is simple to do and once you have it created, you can study the code to see where you went wrong.  You can see how to get started generating code with Gii here: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-start-gii.html

ANSWER FROM COMMENTS: Replace andWhere with orWhere, no results are found because no record can match 'title' and 'en_title' and 'content' and 'en_content'.

Comment: hello i write enough code, for list view we have a data provider in controller and list view is in my view. my gii don't have list view generator

Comment: To generate a listview, you could go into gii, then CRUD generator, and make sure the option "Widget Used in Index Page" is set to ListView rather than GridView.  What I mean by "not enough code" is that there could be many points of failure in the process of creating a listview and it looks like there may not be enough code here to determine where the failure is occurring.  From my experience with Yii2, this doesn't look like enough code to do what you want, that's why I suggested gii.

Comment: At first glance an issue could be that your view is using $model, but I don't see model files that I'm used to using in my own code.  Yii2 likes to have a model that grabs the information from the database and also one that holds information about the fields for form validation.  This may not be a requirement of your's, but that is what I'm used to seeing in a Yii2 project.

Comment: every thing in my webpage is worked very good but at the output my list view show "not found any result" this mean my list view code is no have problem . problem is in my dataprovider and this query beacuse i customize that. the gii generate crude but i don't want crud i want my customize listview

Comment: Oh okay.  You might want to try 'or' instead 'and' for your where statements.  Can a search meet the criteria of being in 'title' and 'en_title' and 'content' and 'en_content'?  Or are you searching for criteria in 'title' or 'entitle' or 'content' or 'en_content'?  Just to make sure you're connecting to your database properly, do a simple query with no WHERE clauses and see if you get any results.

Answer (score 1):

You are submitting `$posts` as `'dataProvider'` while it should be `dataProvidersearch`

Instead of:

```
$posts = $model->getModels();
echo ListView::widget([
    'dataProvider'=>$posts,
    'itemView'=>'search',
    'summary' => '',
    'itemOptions' => [
        'tag' => false

    ],
];
```

Should be:

```
$posts = $model->getModels();
echo ListView::widget([
    'dataProvider'=>$dataProvidersearch,
    'itemView'=>'search',
    'summary' => '',
    'itemOptions' => [
        'tag' => false

    ],
];
```